# Can HTTP requests be unintentionally cached?

Tags: c#, http, caching, networking

The following HTTP fetch should return the string `262`. For some of my users (but not all, or even most) it seems to be returning an older value `261`.

```
string latestVersion = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(
    "http://www.pixelchampions.com/latest.txt");
```

I don't really know why. IIS7 is using mostly default settings. Do some routers/ISPs cache the results of non-query HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (or one of the other RequestCacheLevel settings):

```
WebClient MyClient = new System.Net.WebClient() ;

MyClient.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

string latestVersion = MyClient.DownloadString(
     "http://www.pixelchampions.com/latest.txt");
```